# Listen for UDP messages on Android (React Native)

Tags: android, udp, ip, react-native

I am using this module:

https://github.com/tradle/react-native-udp

This is my code:

```
const Buffer = global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

const dgram = require('dgram')
const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.bind(12345, '10.0.0.24', function(){
    console.log('bound');
});

socket.once('listening', function() {
  console.log('listening');
})

socket.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
});

socket.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
   console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

setInterval(function(){

socket.send(Buffer.from('xyz'), 0, 3, 12345,'localhost', function(err){
      err && console.error(err.stack || err);
   });

}, 2000);



export default socket;
```

it's running on Android, however my UDP socket server does not see messages - my guess is it's not bound to the right host.

Assuming that my diagnosis is correct, my question is:

1. How do find the host of my Android device on my machine?
2. From my Android runtime, how can I see the host machine's ip address - "localhost" in Android might not be the same as "localhost" on my machine?

In the long run, my Android device will need to be able to see the IP of the local wifi router I think, because we are sending UDP transmission from a sensor to the wifi router, and then the Android device needs to be able to read from that, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the address 0.0.0.0 to bind on all interfaces. But you won't be able to receive anything on the virtual device unless you connect it to the host's network with a bridge, and it doesn't look like this is possible with the stock emulator. Try with a real device or with genymotion.
2. You can use the host's IP address.

Comment: well the android (emulator) is its own device, its a difference machine than the machine that's running the emulator, that's all I meant

Comment: yeah this doesn't seem to work. The UDP server running on the Android device doesn't seem to be listening on the same host as the UDP server running on my "regular machine". So they are not talking to each other. I get this logged from React Native:  "server got message: from ip6-localhost:12345". Whereas from the script running directly on my machine I get: "server got message: abc from 127.0.0.1:12345". In both cases the servers are sending messages to themselves, not to each other, if you follow.

Comment: Yes the (emulated) Android device is a separate machine. Let me get this straight: you're trying to send data from some equipment A to the Android device B, and then from B to a third machine C?

Comment: All I am trying to do for the moment is send data from a script X running on my local machine to the Android device. That's it :) The android device has a UDP server running on it, waiting for messages. The script X also has a UDP server running on it. I want the UDP servers to exchange messsages :) Should be simple enough, just can't find the host ip for the Android device (I think that's the problem).

Comment: OK, you need to set the networking mode of the emulator to "bridged" so that it's in the same network as its host. Which emulator do you use?

Comment: thanks, it's AVD, using AVD manager in Android Studio, this is what I got:

Comment: Name: Nexus_10_API_25
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: /home/oleg/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_25.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)
hw.device.name: Nexus 10
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/
showDeviceFrame: yes
AvdId: Nexus_10_API_25
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 10 API 25
hw.device.hash2: MD5:47dc70fd92541dd16c19f9efa3e9db62
hw.ramSize: 1536
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Comment: not sure if that's the info you were looking for though, not sure what you mean by what kind of emulator - all I know is it's an android emulator :) In this case, yes, I am looking to emulate a tablet.

Comment: in the long run, what I will need to do, is be able to look up what devices are connected to a local wifi router and send messages to the right Android device from a sensor using UDP, not sure how that's gonna work yet.

Comment: It looks like the stock emulator may not support this. Try with a real device or with genymotion.

Comment: ok but if so, how do I see the host of that device, if the device is plugged into my computer?

Comment: You'll find the phone's IP address in settings, about phone, status. This doesn't depend on it being plugged in. And for the "look up what devices are connected" I'd suggest looking into multicast networking

Comment: thanks I got it working with a real android device plugged into my machine; appreciate your help

Comment: huh it was working and now it stopped working no idea why! weird, annoying. any common reasons why it would stop working with a real device plugged in ?

Comment: Did the IP address change?

Comment: It did and I thought I accounted for it. My local machine IP changed, but the Android device IP didn't change. Strange.

Comment: ok here is a clue, maybe you can help me with this info: https://github.com/tradle/react-native-udp/issues/34

Comment: udp works when my laptop is set to this IP: 10.0.0.24,   but it doesn't work when it's set to this IP:  10.235.101.163....any idea why that would make a difference?